# How to check if duplicate file exists with paperclip but only in current board

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I currently have paperclip saving the fingerprint with `:fingerprint => :post_file_fingerprint` and my routes are set up like this:

```
  resources :boards, :path => '' do
    resources :posts, :path => 'thread' do
      resources :replies
```

How can I check if `post_file_fingerprint` exists against the newly generated fingerprint, and if it does don't create the post.

I currently I have in my `post.rb`:

```
before_save :check_exists
def check_exists
        if Post.exists?(:post_file_fingerprint [:fingerprint.to_s])
            flash.now[:error] = "Duplicate"
            render @board
        end
end
```

However this code still allows posts to be saved, and has no checking based on board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you trying to rise a flash in a model. There is no way to do that because `flash` is a method defined in `ActionController::Base`.

If you'd like to validate your `Post` model you should implement custom validation.

```
before_save :check_exists
def check_exists
  errors.add(:post_file_fingerprint, "Duplicate") if Post.exists?(post_file_fingerprint: [:fingerprint.to_s])
end
```

I'm not sure your checking condition works properly because you provided too few details about it. Please be sure that works.

And in your controller

```
def create
  # some code
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash[:error] = @post.error.messages
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Works as follows:
Before saving a model AR callback will be initiated, and if `Post` isn't valid — model instance will be set to invalid with message you provided.

AR will not save invalid model into the DB, and then you'll set `flash[:error]` with custom error message.

More details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation).

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

I tested code and made some improvements. The following example works:

```
def check_exists
  errors.add(:post_file, "Duplicate") if Post.exists?(post_file_fingerprint: attributes['post_file_fingerprint'])
end
```

[image: Validation works]

Comment: Sorry about the few details i was a bit tired when I wrote that. The code you provided still allows a duplicate to be posted. When the post is being created paperclip creates a fingerprint `1a0809...`, and I want to check if that fingerprint matches any other in the post_file_fingerprint column as well as having the board_id of the current post.

Comment: @aidiah I improved my answer. Please have a look.